# Storing DOCX files to Parse cloud and retrieving them on iOS

Tags: ios, file, parse-platform

I am trying to store a DOCX file to Parse cloud and then retrieving it , I am facing an issue, when I download file using either SDK PFile class or using URL in both cases the file data gets appended with some header and footer , I want to know how to avoid it so that after saving that data to file I can actually open it with MS Office.
The header is as follows

```
 ------------------------------d6ce5d079979
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test.docx"; filename="test.docx"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

How to get rid of above from file data ?
I have tried using AFNetworking download task to download file as well as PFile in both cases its present in file data.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"DocFiles"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"juoEvcZG9W" block:^(PFObject *docs, NSError *error) {
    // Do something with the returned PFObject in the gameScore variable.

    PFFile *applicantResume = docs[@"docFile"];
    [applicantResume getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
       // NSLog(@"%@",data);
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.docx"];
        NSLog(appFile);
        [data writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
        strPath = appFile;

        QLPreviewController *previewController=[[QLPreviewController alloc]init];
        previewController.delegate=self;
        previewController.dataSource=self;
        [self presentModalViewController:previewController animated:YES];
        [previewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];

    }];

}];
```

The code I am using to upload is as follows

```
    $info = pathinfo($_FILES['userFile']['name']);
 $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
 $newname = $_FILES['userFile']['name'];

 $target = $newname;
 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'], $target);

//error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
$handle = curl_init();

$url = "https://api.parse.com/1/files/".$newname;
$headers = array (

"X-Parse-Application-Id: ************",
"X-Parse-REST-API-Key: *************",
"Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
//"Content-Type:text/plain"
);

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array($newname => "@".$newname);

curl_setopt ($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($handle);
```

Finally also tried downloading file using URL using AFNetworking by creating a download task still the issue remains same.

Comment: Show the code for how you're downloading the file.

Comment: @Wain added the code please take a look

Comment: I should also ask how you uploaded the file (you may well have corrupted it at that point in time...)

Comment: @Wain exactly i thought the same and added that code to

Comment: You shouldn't make your API credentials public (X-Parse-Application-Id and X-Parse-REST-API-Key).

Comment: @JānisK nope they aren't real keys :D thanks anyways